# Should I pass whole object instances or just the value(s) needed into Methods?

Tags: c#, performance, methods

I know the "logical approach" to this question ...

This is *logically correct*:

```
public static Department FindDepartment(Employee emp)
{
    if(emp.ID > 500)
    {
         return new Department("Department for Over 500");
    }else{
         return new Department("Department for 500 and under");
    }
 }
```

... because the Department is really based off the Employee, whereas the following is *logically incorrect*:

```
public static int GetPlusOne(Employee emp)
{
     return emp.ID + 1;
}
```

... because the method really isn't a function of an Employee ... it's just an integer modifier.

That all said (and feel free to point out if I'm in error on that for some reason), Is there any performance lost when passing the entire instance of Employee?

I have an underlying method that will be called most of the time from within a different class and so I'm trying to weigh performance vs. logical here.  But if there's nothing to be worried about performance-wise then the choice becomes logical (haha ... punny).

Comment: why don't define it as an extension method?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to never worry about performance until it becomes a problem. When that happens, use profiling to see where the bottlenecks are - they are almost always not where you might expect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF `Employee` is a `class` then .NET passes a reference (which is basically a pointer) and NOT the instance itself... so performance is rather similar to a real instance method (which too receives a reference to the instance as an *implicit parameter* called `this`).

You can even define them as [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) like:

```
public static Department FindDepartment(this Employee emp)
{
    if(emp.ID > 500)
    {
         return new Department("Department for Over 500");
    }else{
         return new Department("Department for 500 and under");
    }
}
```

then you call it like any instance method on an instance of `Employee`:

```
Employee emp = ...;

Department dep = emp.FindDepartment();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about them being passed as a Pointer.  I'm sure I learned that back in some programming class but had forgotten about it.  Have not played with Extension Methods ... look very interesting and may toy around with them to see if they're the approach for my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of the method call itself, any performance loss will not be enough to matter. More important is the effect this has on your program's maintainability.

If you take an `Employee` as an argument, someone must always ensure that they have en `Employee` before they can call your method. On the one hand, this helps to avoid mistakes where people pass the wrong `int` variable into your method:

```
int plusOne = GetPlusOne(emp.DirectReportId); // oops, didn't you mean EmployeeId?
```

On the other hand, it can be annoying if all I have is the employee's ID, and now I have to do some kind of database access to produce an actual Employee object out of it.

```
foreach(var pinkSlip in pinkSlips)
{
    var employee = GetEmployee(pinkSlip.EmployeeId); // ugh, is this really necessary?
    int plusOne = GetPlusOne(employee);
    ...
}
```

If `GetEmployee` does something expensive like a database roundtrip, the above code could potentially be very slow: not because of the call to GetPlusOne, but because you have to produce an `Employee` when all you're interested in is the ID.

Ultimately, you'll have to make this decision based on how you expect the method in question to be used.

Answer (score 0):

i would actually do both, depFindBy(int employeeId) and depFindBy(Employee employee). not much work and it can be convenient to have both methods later.